# How to delete all conversations all at once in iMessage?

Tags: macbook-pro, messages, high-sierra

It's clear on how to delete conversations in iMessage one by one. Does anyone know how I can delete multiple or all conversations all at once? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no way** to delete multiple or all conversations from the Messages app at once. However, there's a keyboard shortcut that you can employ to speed up deleting multiple conversations in a short duration of time.

Upon selecting a conversation, and hitting <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> brings up a confirmation dialogue as shown:

[image]

Now we would be back to square on if we attempt to click through or select **Delete** button and confirm for each and every conversation.

However, the **Delete** confirmation intent can automatically implied by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Holding down this key combination, one can quickly zip through deleting multiple conversations quickly.

Comment: Option + Command + Delete no longer works in MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Strangely (to me anyway...), if you right-click a conversation and then hold down Option, "Delete conversation" becomes disabled (greyed out) in the pop-up menu. This must be a bug.

Answer (score 5):

In Mojave the keyboard sequence is to first delete the message with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> And then keep <kbd>Command</kbd> pressed and press <kbd>d</kbd> 
You can't delete multiple message at once unfortunately, but keeping the button <kbd>Command</kbd> pressed and alternately press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> makes the delete process a lot less cumbersome.

Comment: Oh thank you, thank you! I cannot believe that Apple let this product ship without the ability to delete multiple messages.

Answer (score 3):

Tested under macOS 10.14.6:

1. Exit Messages.app
2. Backup
3. Deleted all files and folders inside of ~/Library/Messages/
4. Opened Messages.app; stuck "Messages is updating..." window appears
5. Quit Messages.app and delete ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/
6. `killall IMDPersistenceAgent && killall cfprefsd`
7. Rebooted
8. Opened Messages.app - all text messages gone and still logged in

H/T: [TechJunkie](https://www.techjunkie.com/delete-all-imessages-from-mac/), [GonzoWuzHere](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6603407?answerId=26889662022#26889662022), and [512 Pixels](https://512pixels.net/2016/03/fixing-an-endless-the-messages-database-is-bring-upgraded-dialog-box/).

Answer (score 2):

I found it *highly* disturbing that conversations are cached **even if you are no longer signed in with your Apple ID or any other account** (indeed, I had *no* accounts associated with iMessage at all). That is a *bad* thing.

My own answer is less than great, but may prove helpful in combination with the above answers - none of which worked for me because my MacBook was under the control of my IT department. Despite possessing `sudo` powers, there were still some directories I could not operate on.

In my case ...

- In iMessage, I opened `Preferences-> General`
- In the `Keep Messages` drop-down, I selected "`30 Days`"
- Stopped and restarted iMessage

Depending on how many cached conversations are over 30 days, this may take a few seconds - as it did in my case.

Luckily for me, 3+ years of conversations (!!) had been purged for me, leaving only *one* conversation for me to delete.

**OS**: macOS Monterey 12.3.1

---

*An Aside: How did I get Into this mess?*

Because of the administrative software installed (and crucially, updated after the fact) on my laptop, I was **not** allowed to reset my MacBook.

During remote/ pandemic work, I honestly was a bit lazy and allowed some personal stuff to "leak into" my laptop. Since I couldn't reset, the best I could do was try to *manually* wipe out any trace of my personal data.

I will never (as long as I can help it) do that again. In my new position, there is a clear separation of Work and Personal and ne'er the two computers shall inter-relate. Work-supplied MacBook and iPhone have their own, new apple ID.

And yes, this means I walk around with 2 iPhones most of the time. *Sigh*.

Answer (score 1):

So I’m not sure if anyone still is interested in this, but if you lightly slide down over the messages with two fingers it will let you select multiple conversations do be deleted! Discovered this by accident by dropping my phone and it selected them when I caught it, so after a couple minutes trying to recreate the drop I found it! I know it’s a couple years late, but I hope it helps

Comment: This question is about macOS and not iOS.

Comment: Seems like this is the best answer despite the OP asking about OSX

Comment: @Joel - exactly! wow this is huge!

Comment: [How to read English](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjrr_Tc5rD6AhXJMTQIHTrjDXoQFnoECCwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fluentu.com%2Fblog%2Fenglish%2Fhow-to-improve-english-reading%2F&usg=AOvVaw26AAB4OpP38gLGc5JIWHZr)

Answer (score 1):

## Automator Workflow Quick Actions

Created in macos Monterey 12.4

HAK's referenced Applescript is awesome but debugging in future apple os version could be annoying, so another way is with the Automator App. This automation will hopefully prevent hassling with future updates to scripts.

The first Quick Action steps will set you up with a keyboard shortcut to **delete the 1st message**. Then you duplicate this Quick action and copy and paste the "Watch Me Do" Action as many messages you usually have to delete resulting in this action looping as many times as you want, it will error out with you have deleted all your messages...I works so well I cannot even test it anymore :P

### "Messages > Delete Message" Quick Action

Open "Automator.app"

1. Open Automator.app File > New > Quick Action
2. Set "Workflow received current" to "no input" in "Applications/Messages.app"
3. Click Record, then immediately click on Messages.app window
4. Click File in top menu bar
5. Click "Delete Conversation..."
6. Click "Delete" button
7. Then lastly click on the next conversation
8. Stop Automator recording type `CMD + .`
9. Keep only "Click the "File" Menu", "Delete Conversation...", "Click the "Delete" button.", and "Mouse Clicked"... Click then type `BACKSPACE` to delete the other watched actions.
10. Save as "Messages > Delete Message"

### "Messages > Delete x of Messages" Quick Action

With the previous "Automator.app" Quick Action open

1. Automator.app > File > Duplicate
2. Copy + Paste this "Watch Me Do" Automator action as many times as you think you would need to run it. I copied it 15 times. Usually more than plenty.
3. Save as "Messages > Delete x Messages",  x being the amount of times you pasted the "Watch Me Do" Action - I set mine to 15.

These new actions will now be under top menu "File > Services" for the Messages.app but you can also save automations to a keyboard shortcut as well.

### Adding Quick Actions to Keyboard Shortcuts

Now Open "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts"

1. Scroll down to General
2. You should see your new workflow
3. Create a Keyboard shortcut like `SHIFT + CMD + D`

[image: macos Automator Workflow Quick Action to delete messages]

[image: macos Automator Workflow Quick Action to delete messages]

Comment: The question is about deleting conversations, not messages.

Comment: The actions will loop through and delete the whole conversation, I labeled the quick actions with the word 'messages' by mistake but it will remove each conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anybody still needs this, but here is a work around, since almost all of the above are disabled in the latest macos version:

1. first create a keyboard shortcut for 'Clear Transcript' (I used command+X)
2. then select a conversation and use this keyboard shortcut
3. repeat the process for every conversation, and you'll find that the conversation is deleted

This process is cumbersome, but it's easier/quicker with touchbar.
If anyone has a better, smoother option please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Apple deleted many keyboard shortcuts and AppleScript functionality in Messages for Big Sur. After a lot of experimentation I devised an AppleScript that deletes all conversations with one click.

```
# In order to use this script, first open Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts
# and check "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls"

activate application "Messages"

display dialog "Delete all messages?" buttons {"Cancel", "Delete All"} default button 2

tell application "Messages"
    set chatCount to (count of chats)
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Messages"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat chatCount times
            # What appears as É below is actually the Ellipsis (3 dots) character, make sure
            # sure it is the correct character in Script Editor
            click menu item "Delete ConversationÉ" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            delay 1
            # A confirmation dialog box appears, but it is hard to control:
            # - Keystroke "d" using command down NO LONGER WORKS
            # - click button "Delete" in window 1 and similar DO NOT WORK
            # What works: Move focus to "Delete" button and spacebar to click
            key code 48 # tab
            key code 49 # space
            delay 1
            # But now no conversations are selected, so
            click menu item "Go to Next Conversation" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

This code can be cloned from https://gitlab.com/HenryKautz/OSXMessagesDeleteAll

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.